# Technical Full Meaning of HTML

Tags: html

I need to know the full technical meaning of HTML. I know the full form of HTML is HyperText Markup Language. But I don’t know the technical meaning of these words.

- What is HyperText?
- What is Markup?

Comment: All in one [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: [HyperText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext) is a single word, whereas [Markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) is nothing but mere syntax representation.  [DIVE INTO HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) is one such great place to learn.

Comment: Why not buy a dictionary?

Comment: Closing as too broad, you can refer books, you will get tons out there

Comment: This is actually a very specific question, and should not be closed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language

Comment: Why not visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext

Comment: Why not visit [Hyperland (1990)](http://vimeo.com/72501076) with Douglas Adams and Tom Baker?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I believe the restaurant is rather good/weird

Comment: @EdHeal [Milliways](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Milliways)? I like the humanely raised (and even more humanely slaughtered) cheeseburgers. They taste a bit of celery actually.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - It is not as good as the restaurant in Red Dwarf. |Now I appear as a geek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hypertext

[Hypertext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext) is text that has some active parts called [hyperlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink). Hyperlinks can take you directly and immediately to another part of hypertext when activated.

Hyperlinks differ from usual references in that following them requires no effort apart from activating it. E.g. a footnote reference is not a hyperlink because you have to scan the page to find where the footnote is located.

Hypertext is an efficient way of navigating large amounts of text. Anything with its own address can be made “just a click away”, can be the target of a hyperlink.

## Markup

When working with plain text, machines are clueless about its meaning. They are even quite bad at recognizing logical parts of the text and their relative importance and overall meaning. You have to tell them these pieces of information. You want to do so to be able to search the text, to format it, to include non-text resources… [Markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) is the way to do this.

Markup is text mixed with some special-meaning parts, so called [tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_tag). Tags mark structure of text and provide other info. They can refer to a non-text resource, e.g. an image, and they can mark a part of the text as a hyperlink (and provide target address).

For example `<em>` and `</em>` are two tags, that begin and end a part of text marked as *emphasized*: `… part of text marked as <em>emphasized</em>`.

HTML is the most common markup language, but it is not the only one. Wiki code used on Wikipedia, Markdown used on Stack Overflow or GitHub and BBcode used in many bulletin board systems are other well known ones, but there are many many more of them.

## HTML

[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (HyperText Markup Language) is an international standard developed by [World Wide Web Consortium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) (W3C). It is the most wide-spread markup language and it supports hypertext. Web pages are almost exclusively written in HTML (using other technologies like CSS or JavaScript too, of course!).

Note that W3Schools.com have nothing to do with W3C. They must not be mistaken for an official resource. [W3Schools are even considered harmful](http://www.w3fools.com/) to the web by some (me including).

Good resources on HTML are

- [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web)

  - Mozilla Developer Network
  - Many practical resources
- [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/html/)

  - Specifications are the most accurate but hardest-to-read resources.
  - Many beginner-friendly texts can be found there too!

Comment: Perfectly explained i was looking for it for long time thanks so much.

Comment: Mathematically, could we say that `Markup = tags + some data`? Example: `<p>some data</p>`. Could we say that markup is also called as string from the browser perspective?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Very simply put, markup = text + tags. Tags express how the text should be interpreted. I would not think about markup in terms of strings as that does not help anything -- when processing markup programmatically, you can load a whole HTML page in a single string or you can e.g. extract several of its parts as separate strings. Discussing how browsers represent HTML is beyond the scope of this Q&A.

Comment: How does your definition of Hypertext extend to the term Hypermedia?  Is hypermedia just hypertext but with the potential of hyperlinks that point to different media types, such as video, audio, images, etc?  In a different world, would it be more accurate to rename HTTP (hypertext transfer protocol) to HMTP (hypermedia transfer protocol)?

Comment: [Hypermedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermedia) is the extension of hypertext that enables the inclusion of other media (like images, audio, and video) in hypertext, @jmrah. I believe that hypertext itself may contain hyperlinks to other media types, but when it is possible to _embed_ other media types, it becomes hypermedia. E.g. both PDF and HTML may contain hyperlinks and images. I would call a HTML file hypermedia even if it embedded images from an external source (via a https: URI). But it is possible to embed the data itself using data: URI, too.

Answer (score 3):

Hyper-Text refers to text that contains the ability to "link" to some arbitrary other item. Like a footnote but "linked" by a click, and the concept is generally credited to

[As We May Think](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1945/07/as-we-may-think/303881/) (Dr. Vannevar Bush, published by The Atlantic - 1945)

```
Section 7: The main feature of the memex is the ability to tie two things 
together at will. In other words, to be able to associate two arbitrary 
items when wanted.
```

Markup is used to define the structure (and metadata) of the documents (things that are "linked", forming a "web"). It is generally text, and human readable. Even images are specified with a readable link and "alt" text. Further, HTML is a dialect of the earlier [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML) (but adds hyperlinks).

Answer (score 2):

In Networking TCP/IP architecture or protocol suit, HTTP comes under Application Layer. See the below image. Protocol means a set of rule that should follow for an/any application. Similar way, Hypertext Transfer Protocol is an application protocol for distributed, collaborative, hypermedia information systems. 
[image]

Note form wiki-

> 1. [Hypertext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext) is text displayed on a computer display or other electronic device with references (hyperlinks) to other text which the reader can immediately access. The hypertext pages are interconnected by hyperlinks, typically activated by a mouse click, keypress sequence or by touching the screen. Apart from text, hypertext is sometimes used to describe tables, images and other presentational content forms with hyperlinks. Hypertext is the underlying concept defining the structure of the World Wide Web, with pages often written in the Hypertext Markup Language (HTML). It enables an easy-to-use and flexible connection and sharing of information over the Internet.
> 2. A [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) is a modern system for annotating a document in a way that is syntactically distinguishable from the text.

Comment: Cite your sources, in addition to linking to them.  Also, your second link is labeled "enter link description here"...

Answer (score 1):

hyper text means to link somthing or link to texts Markup means HTML commands your web browser to display text and graphics in orderly fashion.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><a href="#link"></a></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

HyperText: hyper means it is not static

so if we click on any hyperlinks it will navigate you to another page

Markup:

It is like marking your text around  tags so it will differentiate the meaning of ordinary text by browser (according to specification of that markup language)

Ex: `<b> I am not ordinary text I am marked within bold tag </b>` - so this text will be in bold when view in browser

Every tag have their own meaning based on that browser will display that annotated text

at present there are so many markup languages Ex: Html,Xml etc...